# React Native Flatlist breaks when you scroll back to initial rendered items

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

```
<FlatList
       style={{ flex: 0.9 }}
       keyboardDismissMode="on-drag"
       keyExtractor={(item, index) => `${item && item.displayName}-${index}`}
       data={authorities}
       onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
       onEndReached={onEndReached}
       windowSize={DEFAULT_PAGE_DATA.size}
       ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader()}
       ListFooterComponent={Authorities.renderFooter({ isFetchingNext })}
       renderItem={renderRow}/>
```

When going downwards everything is displayed as expected but going upwards, some items are either blurred or white out which were already rendered.
Also added
I have tried everything and this github discussion isn't helping either https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23442

Image of issue:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOLgm.jpg

Comment: You have to increase your windowsize

Comment: not working by increasing it